# Compress data while saving to android storage

Tags: android, storage, compression

Is it possible to store data (like photos, doc files, video , any data) to android internal storage in compressed form and while opening the data -> decompress the data (which is stored in the device as compressed form) and then show it to user.

Or Is android doing it by itself while storing and retrieving data ?
Any lead will be helpful.